# How to charge customers for AGPL-3 based solution?

Tags: open-source, pricing, agpl, erp

If I talk about openERP its and source (AGPL-3), I have studied it, but can't find some question e.g

1: we have developed a School Management System using openERP Version 7.0, as according to my understanding, we cannot sale it to any customer as it appears to be free like other modules of openERP.

So I should charge my client for my services? what should be the criteria for that? OR still there is a chance that I can sell my newly developed module?

Answer (score 5):

You can sell your application. There is no limitation on this.

But you have to provide the source code of your created application to your customer if he wishes and your customer can do whatever he wants with the application (even giving it to other people for free).

You can charge your service e.g. developing extensions for your application or fixing bugs. But the customer has also the possibility to fix the bugs himself as he has the source code of the application.

You can also run the application (either on your server or by administrating your customers server) and charge your customer for this.

So there are several ways to get money for your work.